# How to predict where two lines will join in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, lines, trendline

I have the following chart where I have a 'Scope' line and 'Total Effort Done' line and dotted trendlines for each of them. <s>(Since Highcharts does not have support for trendlines, I am just connecting the first and last points of the data using dotted line.)</s> I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline/) for the trendlines.

The objective is to extend the dotted trend lines and find the date (x-Axis value) at which these two lines will meet at the right side (if it's possible and not too far away). How can I do that?

[image]

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/AjJZD/6/

```
$(function () {
    var data1 = [
        [Date.UTC(2013, 4, 28), 40],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 26), 40],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 29), 48],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 21), 48]
    ];
    var data2 = [
        [Date.UTC(2013, 4, 28), 0],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 10), 20],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 19), 22],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 20), 24],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 30), 26],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 1), 28],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 21), 30]
    ];
    var chart_linear = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        colors: ['#912120', '#C00402', '#115DA9', '#115DA9'],
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'shortdot'
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'shortdot'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Scope',
            data: data1
        }, {
            name: 'Scope Change Trend',
            type: 'line',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dashStyle: 'longDash',
            data: (function () {
                return fitData(data1).data;
            })()
        }, {
            name: 'Total Effort Done',
            data: data2

        }, {
            name: 'Velocity',
            type: 'line',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dashStyle: 'longDash',
            data: (function () {
                return fitData(data2).data;
            })()
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the other two answers (especially John Kiernander's), I wrote my own library called ['line_intersection.js'](http://vigneshwaranr.github.io/line_intersection.js/) that provides a function to find the intersection of two straight lines and also provides a function for generating trendlines out of a chart data.

With that library's getTrendlineData and getLineIntersectionData functions, you can do the following

Code:

```
jQuery(function () {
var data1 = [
    [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1), 50],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 2), 58],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 3), 58],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 4), 58]
];
var data2 = [
    [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1), 0],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 2), 12],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 3), 18],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 4), 22]
];
var data1_t = getTrendlineData(data1).data;
var data2_t = getTrendlineData(data2).data;
var options = {
    icptPoint: {
        //name: 'Possible release date',
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            fillColor: '#003300',
            lineColor: '#003300'
        }
    },
    validateIntersection: function(icptX, icptY) {
        // Don't connect the lines if the intersection point is
        // to the left of the chart
        if (icptX < data1_t[0][0] || icptX < data2_t[0][0]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
var forecast = getLineIntersectionData(data1_t, data2_t, options);

var chart_linear = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    colors: ['#990000', '#4679BD', '#990000', '#4679BD'],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineDashStyle: 'shortdot'
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        gridLineDashStyle: 'shortdot'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Estimating release date'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Total issues',
        data: data1
    }, {
        name: 'Closed issues',
        data: data2
    }, {
        name: 'Total issues trend',
        //getLineIntersectionData() may return undefined if lines can not intersect
        data: forecast && forecast.line1_data || data1_t,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dashStyle: 'longDash'
    }, {
        name: 'Closed issues trend',
        data: forecast && forecast.line2_data || data2_t,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dashStyle: 'longDash',
    }]
});
```

Output:

[image]

Live demo: http://vigneshwaranr.github.io/line_intersection.js/demo.html

Thanks a lot John Kiernander for the example that provided the groundwork for the library!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to that depends on a few things...

The short answer: no, there is not a direct and simple way to predict that using the Highcharts API.

In addition, a prediction of this nature, based on those two lines, the way they are, will be completely useless in reality - those trends lines are not based on anything statistical, and then you are extrapolating beyond the data on top of that...

In order to have a useful trending indicator, you need to run linear regression analysis on each of your data sets, and use the slope and intercept to calculate the trend line  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression ).

You can use the same results to predict when those two trend lines will intersect.
BUT - that, in the vast majority of cases, will not give you any sort of accurate prediction.

To get an accurate prediction, you need algorithms that take a variety of factors into account: historical performance, seasonal trends, any number of control variables, current and expected conditions, etc.

tl;dr:

The math required to calculate what you are asking for from what you have is complicated, and won't give you anything useful.

Comment: Thank you. Connecting just the end lines is wrong. I am now using this plugin for the trending indicator. https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline/

Answer (score 1):

I decided to take my calculations a bit further and apply them to your test case.  Here's the code which will answer your original question:

```
$(function () {
    var scope = [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 4, 28), 40],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 26), 40],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 29), 48],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 21), 48]
            ],
        effort = [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 4, 28), 0],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 10), 20],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 19), 22],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 20), 24],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 30), 26],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 1), 28],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 21), 30]
            ],
        // Change in X for scope
        scopeDX = (scope[scope.length - 1][0] - scope[0][0]),
        // Change in Y for scope
        scopeDY = (scope[scope.length - 1][1] - scope[0][1]),
        // Change in X for effort
        effortDX = (effort[effort.length - 1][0] - effort[0][0]),
        // Change in Y for effort
        effortDY = (effort[effort.length - 1][1] - effort[0][1]),
        // Slope for scope
        scopeG =  scopeDY / scopeDX,
        // Slope for effort
        effortG = effortDY / effortDX,
        // Intercept for scope
        scopeI = scope[0][1] - scopeG * scope[0][0],
        // Intercept for effort
        effortI = effort[0][1] - effortG * effort[0][0],
        // X Coordinate for the intersection
        icptX = -1 * (scopeI - effortI) / (scopeG - effortG),
        // Y Coordinate for the intersection
        icptY = scopeG * icptX + scopeI;

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {},
        colors: [ '#912120', '#C00402', '#115DA9', '#115DA9' ],
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'shortdot'
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'shortdot'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Scope',
            data: scope
        }, {
            name: 'Scope Change Trend',
            data: [
                [scope[0][0], scope[0][1]],
                [scope[scope.length - 1][0], scope[scope.length - 1][1]],
                [icptX, icptY]
            ],
            dashStyle: 'longDash'

        }, {
            name: 'Total Effort Done',
            data: effort
        }, {
            name: 'Velocity',
            data: [
                [effort[0][0], effort[0][1]],
                [effort[effort.length - 1][0], effort[effort.length - 1][1]],
                [icptX, icptY]
            ],
            dashStyle: 'longDash'

        }]
    });
});
```

I believe this will work for any case where the lines aren't parallel.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VRf3n/

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the formula from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection#Mathematics

Your formula works in most cases except when it's a vertical line (DX becomes 0 and G becomes infinity and things go wrong from there)